# iOS with MonoTouch - Changing UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I just recently started iOS development using MonoTouch and am getting the the following error on launch of application:

> [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the
>   "SectionTableViewControler" nib but didn't get a UITableView

This started after I changed the "view controller" to inherit from `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. To fix, I went into Xcode 4 and dropped a `UITableView` on the "form" and also created an outlet for the `UITableView` by dragging/dropping in the h file.

How do you change a `UIViewController` to a `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply changing what the IB generated C# class inherits from eg:

```
public class MyViewController : UITableViewController //UIViewController
{
}
```

...or if you simply changed the "Class" type, this is insufficient. The XIB will throw an error on load, since a UITableViewController needs to set it's TableView property in the loadView method. First delete the old object, and then drag and drop a new UITableViewController. You can also check out the tutorial on using Xcode 4 Interface Builder here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/transitioning_from_xcode_3_to_xcode_4

I would actually recommend using MonoTouch.Dialog and DialogViewController to get acclimated with TableViews. It's a great way to learn the concepts, and circle back to the core pattern:

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (almost a year later). Did you actually need the UITableViewController or would a UIViewController that handles a UITableView have worked fine?

For other who might have this problem in the future...

Instead of clearing out the xib and starting again with an empty UITableViewController, I simply made sure the UIViewController could properly handle the UITableView and its data source and delegate. I'll spell it out if that will help anyone else...

1. Inherit from UIViewController (it doesn't actually have to be a UITableViewController to have a UITableView)

   ```
   public partial class MyCustomViewController : UIViewController
   ```
2. Declare a UITableView property with an Outlet attribute

   ```
   private UITableView _tableView;
   [Outlet("tableView")]
   public UITableView TableView {
       get { return _tableView; }
       set { _tableView = value; }
   }
   ```
3. Specify the delegate and data source in the overridden ViewDidLoad method

   ```
   public override void ViewDidLoad ()
   {
       TableView.DataSource = new MyCustomDataSource();
       TableView.Delegate = new MyCustomDelegate(this);

       base.ViewDidLoad ();

       // Perform any additional setup after loading the view...
   }
   ```
4. Make sure your delegate and data source classes inherit from and implement the appropriate methods of UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate respectively.

   ```
   // delegate class
   public class MyCustomDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
   {
       private MyCustomViewController _controller;

       public MyCustomDelegate (MyCustomViewController controller)
       {
           _controller = controller;
       }

       // overridden or additional methods
   }

   // data source class
   public class MyCustomDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
   {      
       public MyCustomDataSource ()
       {
       }

       // overridden or additional methods
   }
   ```
5. In the Connections Inspector of the Utilities panel, make sure the UITableView you've included in your xib is properly linked as `MyCustomViewController`'s **tableView** and `File's Owner` is properly linked as the **dataSource** and **delegate** of your UITableView.

Implementing a generic UIViewController helped me avoid the error entirely. Hope this late answer can help someone else.